# google maps apis v3 and IE 6

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a webpage with google maps and javascript. On IE 6 the map is displayed but the markers are not. I really cannot find why. The maps shows ok on any other browser i can put my hands on.
The webpage is http://www.appleatwork.org
Thanks for your help.
Ciao
b

ps: there is a similar question "IE6: Doesn’t load Google Maps API v3" but in my case
1) the map is being displayed
2) when I create the marker, there is no extra ","

Comment: I could see markers in my IE6,though there is a js error.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps V3 doesn't support [IE6.0](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#browsersupport).

Answer (score 1):

It's important that you upgrade your browser if you wish to use this API. IE6 is almost as bad as using Netscape Navigator, or Machine Code to browse the web.

However, if you're doing this to cater for a client, I have run into similar issues where I thought I'd make sure it works in all browsers, but I couldn't find many people actually still using IE6 because when Windows Update gets released it automatically upgrades the browser to IE7 and even IE8 now.

People still running IE6 may be in large organisations as their systems don't get upgraded as often, but you'll find that most people in these organisations would have downloaded and installed Firefox or Chrome.

The bottom line is, as a Web Developer you no longer need to cater for IE6 as Microsoft have stopped supporting it.

Comment: Daniel, Your comment about Microsoft having dropped support for IE6 is unfounded. Microsoft are supporting IE6 until 2014, which will give organisations enough time to upgrade their systems and software that depend on IE6.

Comment: @StuartShields sorry, you're wrong - http://ie6funeral.com/ March 2010 is when Microsoft called IE6 off. All articles related to the 2014 date were published in 2009. It's gone. Forever.

Comment: >> as a Web Developer you no longer need to cater for IE6 as Microsoft have stopped supporting it. << That's just not true! Many large organisations that still have IE6 (as you mentioned) ALSO have download blockers which prevent users from downloading another browser (that's why our browser stats STILL show ppl coming from IE6). Our % is low, about 0.25%... but at with 50million pages views a month that's 125,000 IE6 hits - and chances to sell. That's a lot of customers to just throw away for the sake of being a lazy coder...

Comment: On my personal website, I have over a thousand unique vistors a month and none of them have been from IE6. Analytics shows in-depth details on which browsers my users utilise. I'll deal with IE6 support reactively not actively, I'll wait until I get some IE6 visitors and then think about support.